# Splunk and python commands in unix

Tags: python, unix, splunk

```
splunkmonitormessage= subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk", "add monitor", path], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

(Ive also tried str(path))

is throwing an error:

> Command error: The subcommand '/opt/logs/node_Default_Node.log' is not
>   valid for command 'add monitor'. Data forwarding configuration
>   management tools.
>
> Commands:
>         enable local-index [-parameter ] ...
>         disable local-index [-parameter ] ...
>         display local-index
>         add [forward-server|search-server] server
>         remove [forward-server|search-server] server
>         list [forward-server|search-server]
>
> Objects:
>         forward-server       a Splunk forwarder to forward data to be indexed
>         search-server        a Splunk server to forward searches
>         local-index          a local search index on the Splunk server

```
sudo /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk add monitor /opt/logs/node_Default_Node.log
```

works completely fine

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `"add"` and `"monitor"` as separate arguments:

```
splunkmonitormessage = subprocess.Popen(
    ["sudo", "/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk", "add", "monitor", path],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

It's how the shell would naturally pass it, so that's what it expects.

Comment: Ugh, I knew it would have been something simple and stupid I was doing wrong. Thanks, man.